# what exactly constitutes a conditional statement in Objective C?

Tags: objective-c, conditional-statements, while-loop

I've been reading the book *Learn Objective C on the Mac,* and I was looking at this bit of sample code:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

int main (int argc, const char * argv[])
{
NSAutoreleasePool * pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];

    NSFileManager *manager;
    manager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];

    NSString *home;
    home = [@"~" stringByExpandingTildeInPath];

    NSDirectoryEnumerator *direnum;
    direnum = [manager enumeratorAtPath: home];

    NSMutableArray *files;
    files = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity: 42];

    // “Slow” enumeration
    NSString *filename;
    while ( filename = [direnum nextObject] )
    {
            if ([[filename pathExtension] isEqualTo: @”jpg”])
            {
                    [files addObject: filename];
            } // end if
    } // end while


    NSEnumerator *filenum;
    filenum = [files objectEnumerator];

    while ( filename = [filenum nextObject] )
    {
            NSLog(@”%@”, filename);
    }

[pool drain];
return 0;
} // main
```

what stood out for me was `while ( filename = [filenum nextObject] )` and I thought, 'how this is actually a conditional statement?' I suppose a call to `[filenum nextObject]` is an NSString with a filename, or *nil*, but how do we get to execute `filename =` while we are evaluating that? can you point me to the correct documentation that would explain more clearly just what is possible here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a conditional statement since every assignation has a value, which is the value on the right hand side assigned to the var on the left.
In this case, the final value turns out to be, either a valid `NSString` object, or nil.
As long as `nil` represents "nothing", the condition is interpreted as false, otherwise it's true.

Comment: so what would while `(myVal=nil)` do?

Comment: false, false, false (min 15 characters)

Comment: So that's pretty powerful. you could stick a whole application into a while conditional then. I'll have to read up on that some more.

Comment: hm. you don't get a paradox if you do `(myVal=nil)' when it is TRUE that myVal, which is nil, is assigned nil?

Comment: no paradox here. this is evaluated as follow : first assign `nil` to `myVal`, then evaluate the final expression value, which is `nil`.

Answer (score 3):

This is actually a feature of C. The while statement takes an expression like an if statement and an assignment is a valid expression. In [this C grammar file](http://www.lysator.liu.se/c/ANSI-C-grammar-y.html) you can see the following is valid

```
IF '(' expression ')' statement
```

and also

```
WHILE '(' expression ')' statement
```

As long as the result from the expression is non zero the condition will be true. A nil value is 0 and will cause the condition to fail. Once the enumerator is done nextObject will return nil and the condition will fail. It is however recommended when doing an assignment as a conditional expression you should surround it with parentheses to state your intentions.

```
while ( (filename = [direnum nextObject]) )
```

Comment: I was looking through the C grammar file link you gave and it's very interesting. It's raising more questions than answers for me, which I'll spend some time looking through... but things like `>>=` and `<<=` popped out... maybe I'll ask another question if i can't find the details on that first.

Comment: ah yes >>= &= |= all fun stuff, these do bit manipulations and assignments with one operator. For example if x = 1 then you do `x <<= 3` x will then equal 8.

Comment: oh that's taking 001 and changing it into 100? thus moving it over 3 notches? so 00010100011 in that case would change to 01010001100? I'm sure that's useful somewhere, but i don't know where just at the moment... maybe if i wanted to store binary parameters in an integer?

Comment: Getting way off topic :) here, but close 0001 would become 1000, it is 3 shifts your example was 2 shifts. And this is commonly used in algorithms and encryption (which uses algorithms).

Answer (score 2):

`while ( filename = [filenum nextObject] )`

This statement is complex and performs multiple operations.

1. `[filenum nextObject]` method is called and returns an NSString
2. `filename =` gets assigned the address of the NSString
3. the value of `filename` is evaluated as a condition for the `while ( ... )`
   operation

As you pointed out if the returned value is `nil` then filename equals `nil` and the condition evaluates to false else filename is non-zero and the condition evaluates to true.

Many programers don't like this kind of syntax.  It is terse and can be difficult to maintain.  Compilers will generate a warning, to flag a common syntax error for when the developer actually intend to compare the two values,

`while ( filename == [filenum nextObject] )`

It would be cleaner to write the original statement as

`while ( (filename = [filenum nextObject]) != nil )`

This statement will behave the same as the original but eliminates the ambiguity of the assignment and the conditional operations.

Comment: I definitely like that more, for the readability of it... but this concept of "killing two birds with one stone" of not only assigning a value but also evaluating it looks like a nice time saver that probably makes more sense to a seasoned programmer, but which can be problematic for a beginner such as myself.

Answer (score 1):

You have raised a good question.  Consider the code

```
while ( obj = [enumerator nextObject] ) {
    printf( "%s\n", [[obj description] cString] );
}
```

The reason why `while ( obj = [array objectEnumerator] )` works is because objectEnumerator returns nil on the last object. Since in C nil is usually 0, this is the same as false. `( ( obj = [array objectEnumerator] ) != nil )` might be preferable

Source :  [Click This Link](http://www.otierney.net/objective-c.html)  !

In your case, `((filename = [direnum nextObject]) )` is another way of doing this to avoid compiler errors.

Comment: `nil` does not exist in C, but in Objective-C, and it is _always_, not "usually", 0. It's defined as `((void *)0)`.

Answer (score 0):

The expression

```
(file = [filenum nextObject])
```

Will be executed each time through the loop. After it is excecuted it is then evaluated as the Boolean condition for the if statement

It's the same as a normal statement like

```
x = 13 * 4;
```

Everything to the right of the equals is executed and then it is assigned to the variable x.